# JavaScript - jQuery: how to create array item based on string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

There is array (in JavaScript) of items written in the following way:

```
var arr = [ 
    [1, 2, 'abc', 3, 'cab'],
    [3, 4, 'def', 5, 'ghi'],
    ];
```

There is a string variable that contains string representation of next item:

```
var s = "[6, 7, 'new', 8, 'something']";
```

How can I convert string into a new "item" that can be pushed into 'arr' array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either `eval` the string if it's safe (not user input):

```
arr.push(eval(s));
```

Or, strip the first and last characters of the string, and then split it by the comma (provided there are no commas within the array values themselves):

```
arr.push(s.substring(1, s.length - 1).split(","));
```

Comment: `.eval()` would work. The `.split()` method sort of works, but wouldn't give the actual values that I'm guessing OP wants. They'll all be Strings, some with extra spaces, some with single quotes inside. `["6"," 7"," 'new'"," 8"," 'something'"]`

Comment: It is not a user input. Thank you!

Comment: @patrick - you're right about the split. Moment of carelessness and it completely didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: That will work if OP modifies the string to make it valid JSON.